# Regular expressions: How to enter a group name into a set of characters to exclude

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match 3-character words of type `aba`, so `aba` or `xyx` should match, but *aaa* should NOT match.

Tried the pattern

```
r'(.)([^\1])\1'
```

which, in agreement with the documentation on groups, doesn't work.
This is a simplified question, of course. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try `(.)(?!\1).\1` - a *negative lookahead* to make sure the second character doesn't match the first, then a dot to match whatever the second character happens to be.

Comment: @jasonharper That would be a good answer.

Comment: Try `(?'name'.)[^(?&name)](?&name)` https://regex101.com/r/6BogwK/1

Comment: @lorvindc That would not work. `(?&name)` in a character class mean those characters literally.